# Can OSX still sync dropbox while "asleep"?

Tags: sleep-wake, dropbox

If a Mac Mini running macOS 10.11 is in sleep mode, but powered on and connected to the network, will Dropbox still sync in the background?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consult Apple's [documentation about Power Nap](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204032).

Mac Minis (Late 2012 and later) are Power Nap compatible.

From what I can see, the only services which are available when a Power Nap compatible computer is in sleep mode are Apple-only:

**If your Mac supports Power Nap, these activities can occur while your Mac is asleep:**

- Mail receives new messages.
- Contacts keep up to date with changes made on other devices.
- Calendar receives new invitations and calendar updates.
- Reminders keep up to date with changes made on other devices.
- Notes keep up to date with changes made on other devices.
- Documents stored in iCloud keep up to date with changes made on other devices.
- Photo Stream keeps up to date with changes made on other devices.
- Find My Mac updates the location of the Mac, so you can find it while it's asleep.
- VPN on demand continues working so that your corporate email updates securely. (Power Nap supports VPN connections that use a certificate to authenticate, not VPN connections that require entering a password.)
- Mobile Device Management can remotely lock and wipe your Mac.

**And these activities can occur while your Mac is asleep and plugged in to an AC power outlet:**

- Software updates download.
- Mac App Store items (including software updates), download in the background.
- Time Machine performs backups.
- Spotlight performs indexing.
- Help Center content updates.
- Wireless base stations can wake your Mac using Wake on Wireless.

<sub>Content lifted directly from the Apple Support document linked above.</sub>

Comment: Thanks @iconDaemon do you know if dropbox will stay syncing whilst in power nap ?

Comment: You'd have to ask [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/support).

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox (as of March 2019) appears to be Power Nap compatible. I started 14GB syncing (uploading) before I went to bed, closed the lid, and it was all synced by morning.  Computer was cool to touch in the morning so I don't think it was awake with lid closed.